# Convert list to comma-delimited string

Tags: python, string

The following is the list that I have:

```
>>> issue_search
[<JIRA Issue: key=u'NEC-1519', id=u'991356'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'NEC-1516', id=u'991344'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'NEC-1518', id=u'990463'>]
>>>
```

I was using the following:

```
issue_string = ','.join(map(str, issue_search))
```

But the output is:

```
NEC-1519, NEC-1516, NEC-1518
```

I am confused on the output. How is only the `key` getting displayed? How to get the other text too in the string format?

Comment: That is not valid Python syntax. How did you get that output?

Comment: Did you check the `__str__` or `__repr__` methods?

Answer (score 2):

What you see in the list is the values returned by each object's [`__repr__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__).  If you want these values, map the list to [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) instead of `str`:

```
issue_string = ','.join(map(repr, issue_search))
```

Below is a demonstration with `decimal.Decimal`:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> lst = [Decimal('1.2'), Decimal('3.4'), Decimal('5.6')]
>>> lst
[Decimal('1.2'), Decimal('3.4'), Decimal('5.6')]
>>> print ','.join(map(str, lst))
1.2,3.4,5.6
>>> print ','.join(map(repr, lst))
Decimal('1.2'),Decimal('3.4'),Decimal('5.6')
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `str` on the objects within `issue_search` before joining them. So obviously, the call of `str` on a “JIRA Issue” will only result in the key.

The return value of `str` is determined by an object’s `__str__` method which is likely defined in the described way for the “JIRA Issue” type. If you cannot change the method, you could also call `repr` on the objects instead, or specify a custom format function:

```
>>> ', '.join(map(lambda x: '{} ({})'.format(x.key, x.id), issue_search))
'NEC-1519 (991356), NEC-1516 (991344), NEC-1518 (990463)'
```

Comment: In your final example, rather than `map`ing a `lambda` function you should just use a generator expression: `", ".join("{} ({})".format(x.key, x.id) for x in issue_search)`. The functional style of `map` is only really a better choice than a genexp (or a list/dict/set comprehension) if the function you're applying already exists (like it does when you're using `str` or `repr`).